# How to increment the counting for each non-consecutive value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a simple representation of my table:

```
    ID | GA
   ----------
    1  | 1.5
    2  | 1.5
    3  | 1.2
    4  | 1.5
    5  | 1.3
```

I would like to count the number of occurrence of the `GA` column's values **BUT** the count should not increment when the value is the same as the next row.

What I would like to expect is like this:

```
    ID |  GA  | COUNT
   -------------------
    1  | 1.5  |  1
    2  | 1.5  |  1
    3  | 1.2  |  1
    4  | 1.5  |  2 
    5  | 1.3  |  1
```

Notice that `GA = 1.5` count is **2**. This is because there is a row between `ID 2 & 4` that *breaks the succession* of `1.5`.

> NOTE: The ordering by `ID` also matters.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
SELECT ID,GA,COUNT (*) OVER (
 PARTITION BY GA
 ORDER BY ID
) COUNT
FROM (
 SELECT 1 AS ID,'1.5' AS GA
 FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 2,'1.5' FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 3,'1.2' FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 4,'1.5' FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 5,'1.3' FROM DUAL
) FOO
ORDER BY ID;
```

But the result is far from expectation:

```
    ID |  GA  | COUNT
   -------------------
    1  | 1.5  |  1
    2  | 1.5  |  2
    3  | 1.2  |  1
    4  | 1.5  |  3 
    5  | 1.3  |  1
```

Notice that even if they are consecutive values, the count is still incrementing.

Comment: You wrote "I would like to count the number of occurrence of the GA column's values BUT the count should not increment when the value is the same as the next row." Did you mean "same as the previous row"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you are asking for a kind of a running total, not just a global count.

Assuming, that the input data is in a table named `input_data`, this should do the trick:

```
WITH
with_previous AS (
    SELECT id, ga, LAG(ga) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS previous_ga
      FROM input_data
),
just_new AS (
    SELECT id,
           ga,
           CASE
               WHEN previous_ga IS NULL
                 OR previous_ga <> ga
               THEN ga
           END AS new_ga
      FROM with_previous
)
SELECT id,
       ga,
       COUNT(new_ga) OVER (PARTITION BY ga ORDER BY id) AS ga_count
  FROM just_new
 ORDER BY 1
```

See sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/187e13/1

Result:

```
 ID |  GA | GA_COUNT
----+-----+----------
  1 | 1.5 |        1
  2 | 1.5 |        1
  3 | 1.2 |        1
  4 | 1.5 |        2
  5 | 1.3 |        1
  6 | 1.5 |        3
  7 | 1.5 |        3
  8 | 1.3 |        2
```

I took sample data from [@D-Shih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176071/d-shih)'s [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2cb362/27)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the problem, this is a variation of a gaps-and-islands problem.  You want to enumerate the groups for each `ga` value independently.

If this interpretation is correct, then I would go for `dense_rank()` and the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by ga order by seqnum_1 - seqnum_2)
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by ga order by id) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
order by id;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/NKQD84618) is a rextester.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery with LAG and SUM anlytic functions:

```
SELECT id, ga,
       sum( cnt ) over (partition by ga order by id) as cnt
FROM (
  select t.*,
       case lag(ga) over (order by id)
            when ga then 0 else 1
       end cnt
  from Tab t
)
order by id

| ID |  GA | CNT |
|----|-----|-----|
|  1 | 1.5 |   1 |
|  2 | 1.5 |   1 |
|  3 | 1.2 |   1 |
|  4 | 1.5 |   2 |
|  5 | 1.3 |   1 |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ddd1/5